# MYSQL - Insert result of concat of multiple rows based on ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I've searched and searched but I think I'm missing something. What I'm trying to accomplish is saving the result of a concat on a single table where multiple rows are combined based on ID.

My table has only 3 columns:
ID - Order_items_id - Customization

The ID is unique but will not matter in the long run.

What I want to accomplish is to concat all rows with the same `order_item_id`. The concat would only apply to `customizations`.

An example of my table:

```
ID - order_item_id - customization
0    1231            19;1
1    1231            75;1
2    2345            10;5
```

I can get my result to show up the way I want via the following query:

```
SELECT `order_item_id`, group_concat(`customizations` separator ';')
FROM `ojs_order_ing_export`
GROUP BY `order_item_id`

ID - order_item_id - customization
0    1231            19;1;75;1
2    2345            10;5
```

Now I'm a bit stumped as to how I can insert the result of this query in a 3rd column, or update the `customization` column to save the results of the concat query.

The goal of this is to group all data in `customization` based on `order_item_id` into a single row so I can then join `customization` column with another table.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what you mean by "My only issue is actually saving those results."

Comment: I need to insert the results of my concat into a new column to be then combined with a 2nd table.

Comment: than you can use insert statement.

Comment: That's what I'm having issues with. I will find, and post code, in a moment of my previous attempt.

Comment: question is still not clear give example output which you want finally..

Comment: The column I am looking to combine is `customization` based on matching `order_item_id` then insert result into new column `arbitrary_name`. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that i absolutely understood your goal, but looks like you should so somemthing like `INSERT-SELECT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO my_new_table (order_item_id, order_item_customizations)
SELECT `order_item_id`, group_concat(`customizations` separator ';')
FROM `ojs_order_ing_export`
GROUP BY `order_item_id`
```

or, for example

```
CREATE TABLE my_new_table
SELECT `order_item_id`, group_concat(`customizations` separator ';')
FROM `ojs_order_ing_export`
GROUP BY `order_item_id`
```

If you want to have the same table but with "merged" values – just swap original and new table.